# file flex air exec

Tags: apache-flex, file, air, exec

I read this [flex air exec](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/464862file) thread. But currently I installed Air 1.5.2 but can't run `fscommand()` function. Is there any information? Please help me.

Comment: I saw  http://forums.adobe.com/thread/464862 site.
i executed fscommand("exec","test.exe") from AIR desktop application client side but output is zero is there any help?
i have no option using flash only AIR
under this situation pls help me

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to open an executable from air.